# Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' when i try to split a row from csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am new to python so please take that into consideration before you start being too critical.

I have a CSV file with entries like:-

```
for 30 days
for thirty working days
for 20 weeks
for 2 months
```

I want to split each row with single space as delimiter :-

```
(for) (30) (days)
(for) (thirty) (working) (days)
```

now i want to pass each word to word2number so that my `'thirty'` will be given as `'30'`

now for the first row as the `'30'` is already a number i want to multiply it with 1 as it says days. if it was followed by `'n weeks'` then `'n*7'`. similarly `'*30'` for months and `'*365'` for years.

the result of the multiplication should be outputed in the corresponding cell of that row.

**Right now my code is**

```
import csv
from word2number import w2n

with open("test_term.csv", "rb") as file1:
        reader = csv.reader(file1)
        extractedlist = list(reader)
        #print extracted
def split_line(text):

    # split the text
    words = text.split('')

    # for each word in the line:
    for word in words:

        # print the word
        print(word)

for extracted in extractedlist:
    worn = split_line(extracted)
```

im getting error `'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split''`.

i need to pass the splitted words to `'w2n.word_to_num(word)'` which will convert the word to number. if it does not give an output just skip to next word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reader within the CSV module returns a 2-dimensional like list. In truth, it returns a generator that acts kind of like a 2-dimensinal list when referencing.  Where there are n amount of columns in each entry of the list. You need to add a for loop to your reader. So when you go to split the line and print it make a loop for through each row *and* column. Here is what the code might look like.

```
for extrRow in extractedList:
  for extrColumn in extrRow: # for each entry in the row
    worn = split_lines(extrColumn)
```

Even if your file has no commas CSV will still try to split the line by commas. Python will return this as a list so you will just have one entry per row. If you want more information on this, take a look at [Python's CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), the first example split the rows into columns.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to check if the splitted word is either 'days or months or years' ?

Comment: What do you mean check the split word? You can always just use an if statement, `if "month" in str: doSomething()`.

Comment: csv.reader doesn't return a 2-dimensional list because it would consume too much RAM reading big CSV-files. It returns a generator: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader` builds a generator yiending lists, not strings. In other words, values are already splited.